# Why my function does nos continue executing the other cases when data is not found in one?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I use exception and continue statements but even though i gett error ORA-

```
06503. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Function returned without value"
*Cause:    A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was
           executed.
```

I tries using an exception and continue.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_valor;

  EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN v_valor:= 0 ; 

return result;

-- In the loop
 CONTINUE WHEN v_valorNuevo = 0;
```

I expect to get the rest cases when one case has no data.

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly why you're getting this error, since your example code is not a complete function. However, that error means you're exiting the function in such a way that a return value hasn't been set. Check all the ways you could exit the function (e.g. through exception paths as well as through non-exception paths) and add in the missing `return`(s) where appropriate.

Comment: It is impossible for us to answer this question without seeing the whole code, or at least a redacted version of it which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you `return result` in the exception case only. All cases need to return a value for a function.

Comment: I return result in all cases

Comment: @ArturoHotsulyak Is it possible to share the whole code ?

Comment: @ArturoHotsulyak you need to read the documentation for Oracle Block Structures. The code posted will execute  the 'return result' statement only on a NO DATE FOUND condition.